# Cannot find old version Microsoft module file

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile an old [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) solution (developed using previous version of VS) using Microsoft VS 2015. 
I got some errors like:

> ERROR: Unable to find module file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Merge Modules\policy_9_0_Microsoft_VC90_MFCLOC_x86.msm`

---

> ERROR: Unable to find module file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_ATL_x64.msm`

I looked at the directory and only find `Microsoft_VC140_MFCLOC_x86.msm` and I don't see a file like `Microsoft_VC140_ATL_x64.msm`.

How can I update the program so that I can fix these errors? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Simple question, can you compile a C++ program today with a compiler like Borland Turbo C++. Probably no. The best you might be able to do is to find that file that's missing from the old VS library but the new VS might still have dependencies. You might need to refactor the code.

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest how to refactor the code? Not sure where to start.

Comment: I'd have to see your code, I'm not a mind reader. I know it sounds horrible but microsoft makes a fortune doing stuff like this. I also don't want to sound like a conspiracy theorist because GCC too breaks stuff but this is probably $$$.

Comment: Do you just need the .vcxproj file? The file is too big for here. Could you suggest where I can learn about things like this?

Comment: Did you write the code yourself. What is the code about anyway. The one thing you should try to do is to find what part of your code depends on that file that's missing and fix that instead. Maybe it's a function call or something else really basic. You should try finding that one file though and seeing if you can place it into your new VS folder. It's probably because because you need micro$oft tech $upport.

Comment: You might also want to try to take the source files out of the old project itself and start a new project without them. What I'm implying is that the error might not be the code but the IDE architecture itself and the old saved project file needs a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The project is building an installer.  The merge modules (.msm) are required to be able to install the product.  Consider that if that is your first error, you have built the .exe / .dll of your project and work out how to install your new code based on your more updated dependencies.

The likelihood, is that the merge-modules have been added from the original dependencies for the build.

As you have upgraded the project, they are probably not the correct merge modules for the upgraded project.

Comment: Sorry, did not get your point. Not sure how to install the required merge modules.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as atl140.dll. Don't worry, it's simply not necessary anymore. According to Microsoft, ATL is now provided as headers and a static library (atls.lib):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Therefore, you can safely remove the (non-existing) Microsoft_VC140_ATL_*.msm from your dependency.

Microsoft_VC140_MFCLOC_*.msm exists on my system. If you don't have that, your Visual Studio 2015 needs a repair or reinstall.